# WordPress Appointkart plugin issue in iphone device

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook, customization

When plugin  page load then by default open calendar. So how I hide the by default open calendar.

[image: See the image]

in Iphone page load calander open. [website link](http://demo.samaxxpreview.com/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add code samples or links to live examples if you want to be helped.

Comment: please check this link
http://demo.samaxxpreview.com/ @SergChernata

Answer (score 0):

You have :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hide_cal').delay(8000).fadeIn(400);
});
```

buried at the end of:

```
/wp-content/plugins/appointkart/assets/js/jquery.pickmeup.js
```

Something like that doesn't even belong in the plugin file. Perform all initiation in a separate `js` file.

Comment: Yes I have added this js code, sometime delay calendar pop but no any out put at this time ,
so how can i hide this calendar in iPhone devices. i have tried.
@Serg Chernata